# Linking one value of a in ipywidgets.FloatRangeSlider to a FloatText widget

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

In JupyterLab, using the IPyWidgets module, I am trying to link the lower value of a FloatRangeSlider to the value of a FloatText.

I tried this code:

```
from ipywidgets import link, FloatRangeSlider, FloatText
# Create the widgets
slider = FloatRangeSlider(min=0.0, max=100.0, value=(25.0, 75.0))
text = FloatText(value=slider.value[0])

# Link the value of the slider to the floattext box
link((text, 'value'),(slider, 'value'))

# Display the widgets
display(slider, text)
```

but of course, FloatRangeSlider.value is a tuple containing 2 floats, while FloatText.value is a float.
'TraitError: The 'value' trait of a FloatRangeSlider instance expected a tuple, not the float 25.0.'

Using the transform argument:
`link((text, 'value'),(slider, 'value'),transform=lambda x: x[0])`
Also fails since the link is bidirectional (it works with a uni-directional dlink).
'TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable function object'

How to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and was able to solve it through trial and error, but found the explanation in the [traitlets documentation](https://traitlets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/utils.html#traitlets.link) afterwards (which is used in ipywidgets, but I couldn't find this detail in the ipywidgets documentation).

The transform is bidirectional and you have to pass an iterable of callables, one for each direction.

Here is a minimal example adapted from your code for a `FloatRangeSlider` linked to two `BoundedFloatText` widgets, one for the lower and one for the upper value of the slider:

```
from ipywidgets import link, FloatRangeSlider, BoundedFloatText

# Create the widgets
slider = FloatRangeSlider(min=0.0, max=100.0, value=(25.0, 75.0))
text_lower = BoundedFloatText(value=slider.value[0], min=slider.min, max=slider.max, step=slider.step)
text_upper = BoundedFloatText(value=slider.value[1], min=slider.min, max=slider.max, step=slider.step)

# The transforms are bi-directional and should be an iterable of callables (one for each direction)
# (binding of slider variable to the lambda is not necessary in this example, but might help to avoid confusion elsewhere)
transforms_lower = [lambda value, slider=slider: [value, slider.value[1]],
                    lambda value, slider=slider: value[0]]
transforms_upper = [lambda value, slider=slider: [slider.value[0], value],
                    lambda value, slider=slider: value[1]]

# Limit the range of the text widgets, so that we cannot set min > max or max < min on the slider
# (using the BoundedFloatText instead of FloatText prevents setting out of slider range values)
link((text_lower, 'max'), (slider, 'value'), transform=transforms_upper)
link((text_upper, 'min'), (slider, 'value'), transform=transforms_lower)

# Link the values
link((text_lower, 'value'), (slider, 'value'), transform=transforms_lower)
link((text_upper, 'value'), (slider, 'value'), transform=transforms_upper)

# Display the widgets
display(slider, text_lower, text_upper)
```

Since this makes the slider readout superfluous, you can disable by passing `readout=False` to the slider.